# Create a method that checks if a list is empty

Tags: android, list, object

What im trying to do is to end the game when a list of snakepart´s is empty.
This method removes one object from the list:

```
 public void diet() {
    parts.remove(parts.get(parts.size()-1));
}
```

This method here should check if my list of snakeparts is empty right?

```
public boolean checkStarved() {
    int len = parts.size();
    SnakePart head = parts.get(0);
    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        SnakePart part = parts.get(i);
        if(parts.isEmpty())
            return true;
    }        
    return false;
}
```

Though it doesen´t. 
I return the boolean in the World class during update class like this:

```
if(snake.checkStarved()){

            gameOver = true;

    }
```

The snakepart class looks like this:

```
public class SnakePart {
public int x, y;

public SnakePart(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

}

And this is the basic Snake class :

```
 public Snake() {        
    direction = UP;
    parts.add(new SnakePart(5, 6));
    parts.add(new SnakePart(5, 7));
    parts.add(new SnakePart(5, 8));
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    if(state == GameState.Running)
        state = GameState.Paused;

    if(world.gameOver) {
        Settings.addScore(world.score);
        Settings.save(game.getFileIO());
    }
}
07-08 20:39:50.341: E/AndroidRuntime(2957): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4575
```

07-08 20:39:50.341: E/AndroidRuntime(2957): Process: com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom, PID: 2957
07-08 20:39:50.341: E/AndroidRuntime(2957): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
07-08 20:39:50.341: E/AndroidRuntime(2957):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
07-08 20:39:50.341: E/AndroidRuntime(2957):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
07-08 20:39:50.341: E/AndroidRuntime(2957):     at com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom.GameScreen.drawWorld(GameScreen.java:147)
07-08 20:39:50.341: E/AndroidRuntime(2957):     at com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom.GameScreen.present(GameScreen.java:131)
07-08 20:39:50.341: E/AndroidRuntime(2957):     at com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.impl.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:40)
07-08 20:39:50.341: E/AndroidRuntime(2957):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: Why do you need a for loop if you just want to check if the list is empty?

Comment: this can never return true, as being in the loop implies that `isEmpty` is false, just like being able to call `get(i)` without crashing.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that aswell, but I changed it to the answer that was posted below. Still crashing when list is empty.

Comment: Do post your logs and the function it is crashing in?

Comment: I have now... what a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public boolean checkStarved() {
    int len = parts.size();
    SnakePart head = parts.get(0);
    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        SnakePart part = parts.get(i);
        if(parts.isEmpty())
            return true;
    }        
    return false;
}
```

to

```
public boolean checkStarved() {
        return parts.isEmpty();
}
```

Also

```
parts.remove(parts.get(parts.size()-1));
```

Can be reduced to

```
parts.remove(parts.size()-1);
```

Comment: I changed it, still the same problem. When the list is empty the game crashes! The gameOver method DO work so it is something else.

Comment: Can you post the logcat and gameOver function as well?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check if parts.isEmpty() or part.isEmpty()? I notice in the for loop that you get part and then never use the variable.

Comment: They are the same? part is just an instance for the parts if im not enteirly out of order..

Comment: I don't know without seeing the code if it's the same. It is a customized class I assume, or at least I am not familiar with SnakePart. If it's the same, then you can remove it from the for loop since the variable is never used (which is why I thought there may be a mistake). Have you debugged this to see what happens and what the method returns?